# Find a Base for Map(R,R)

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I have trouble finding a basis for $Map(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.
While I know what a/the (standard)basis is for $\mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$, that should be $\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right) $ I can't seem to grasp how exactly a basis for $Map(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ could look like.

I have the following Vectorspace $V := \{ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \mid \textrm{ there exists } a_0,\ldots,a_4 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^4 a_i x^i$ for all  $ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$
and there is a linear Map $\varphi: V \to V$ with $\varphi(f)(x) = f''(x) - x \cdot f'(x) + f(x-1).$

I have problems with the following two questions:

1) Calculate the matrix $M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}(\varphi)$ with respect to a base $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$.

2) Find a basis for $ker(\varphi)$

Now how does a base B for $Map(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ look like? Is there something like a canonic basis for $Map(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$? I'm stuck and I'd be grateful for any hint into the right direction!

Could I assume that there is some $e$ which is the canonic base for $Map(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that $M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}(\varphi)  = e*(f''(x) - x \cdot f'(x) + f(x-1)) $?

For clarity: $M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}(\varphi)$ is the Transformation matrix.

Comment: You are looking for a basis of $V$, not of the set of all maps. You are right that for all maps, it is quite hard to find a basis. However, your maps in $V$ are quite special, that should help in finding the basis.

Comment: @Dirk Well it seems like I was thinking towards the wrong direction. Let's see if I can come up with something useful.

Comment: I think I found a basis, it should be something like $ B:=\{g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^i$ for all $i\in[0,4]\}$ so our basis B looks like this $(1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4)$ and calculating $M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}(\varphi)$ is easy then.

Comment: I have another Question though. We now want to calculate $ker(\varphi)$ and $\varphi(x) = -3a_{4}x^4-2a_{3}x^3-a_{2}x^2+12a_{4}x^2+6a_{3}x+a_{2}-a_{1}-a_{3}-a_{4}$ and we know that $ker(\varphi) = \{x $such that $\varphi(x) = 0\}$. This is only the case if $a_i \in [0,4]$ $a_i = 0$ for all $i$. Does that mean ker($\varphi) = 0$ ?